# WPF ListBox KeyBinding not firing

Tags: wpf, listbox, inputbinding

I have a ListBox which I am attempting to bind the "Delete" key to delete an item (binding to a delete command and updated the collection), but the event never get fired. More interestingly, the event get fired when the form is first time loaded. I do have multiple listbox and I want to handle delete accordingly.

here is the xaml code:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ItemListView1" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemList}" 
      SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem}">
    <ListBox.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Delete" Command="{Binding RemoveListView1SelectedItem}" />
    </ListBox.InputBindings>
</ListBox>
```

here is the view model:

```
    private ICommand _removeListView1SelectedItem;
    public ICommand RemoveListView1SelectedItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _removeListView1SelectedItem ?? (_removeListView1SelectedItem = new RelayCommand(param =>
            {
                if ((SelectedItem.HasValue)
                    && !ItemList.Contains(SelectedItem.Value))
                {
                    ItemList.Remove(SelectedItem.Value);
                    SelectedItem = null;
                    OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
                    OnPropertyChanged("ItemList");
                }
            }));
        }
    }

This is the RelayCommand:

public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute) : this(execute, null)
        {
        }

        public RelayCommand(Action<object, object> execute) : this(execute, null)
        {
        }

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
        {
            if (execute == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

            _execute = execute;
            _canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        public RelayCommand(Action<object, object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
        {
            if (execute == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

            _executeMultiParam = execute;
            _canExecute = canExecute;
        }
```

Comment: Can you find out who is receiving the delete key when you press it?  Who has keyboard focus etc?

Comment: I used Snoop just now, found on there is a keydown event on the ListBoxItem, and it is handled by the ListView, hanlded is false

Comment: one more question:  which variant of the RelayCommand are you using?  I always use the one with two constructor arguments.

Comment: no link?  Did you mean to post a link?

Comment: sorry I update the question so I can post code

Comment: And what's the default value in the base class when a null predicate is provided? It might be the problem...

Comment: default value for predicate is null

Comment: the problem is the command not even being triggered at all

Comment: A predicate cannot have a value of null.  It looks like that's why the command never fires.  Read: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz(v=vs.110).aspx  I can post a tentative answer to help if nobody else wants to try.  It may fix it, or may not.  I haven't seen the base class.